# How to alter drupal views filter by start date query

Tags: views

I need to display only future events with start and end date greater than or equal to today's date. I am using drupal with oracle. When i am trying in views UI, its giving me an SQL error.

Comment: What error? What's your setup? We can't reliably guess without data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this module [Views between dates filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_between_dates_filter)  I suppose this may help you

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I tried this module. But its only showing one date field in exposed form.

Comment: In Drupal views in filter criteria add a field say Between Dates(node) in that you ll find an options,You can configure according to ur need

Comment: Between Dates (node) form field is a single field. No start and end date.

Comment: else use like this,,,,,,steps as follows,    1) in ur content type create a field like date ith field_type 'Date' check the field settings collect the end date 2)
    Under Fields, add Content: Event Date and set the Display to "Start Date Only"
    Under Fields, add Global: Custom Text and set Text to -
    Under Fields, add Content: Event Date and set the Display to "End Date Only"
    Under Field Settings, Set the three fields above as Inline.
3) finally when u add content check show the end date ...... I hope this may help you